# Unable to parse DateTime-string with AM/PM marker

Tags: java, simpledateformat

The string I want to format looks like this:
String datetime = "9/1/10 11:34:35 AM"

Following pattern for SimpleDateFormat works:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yy h:mm:ss");
Date d = sdf.parse(datetime);
System.out.println(d);

Output> [Wed Sep 01 11:34:35 CEST 2010]
```

However I need to parse the AM/PM marker as well, and when I add that to the pattern I receive an exception.

Pattern that doesn't work:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yy h:mm:ss a");
```

I have tried with this also with same exception:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yy h:mm:ss aa");
```

Exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "9/1/10 11:34:35 AM"
```

I have looked through the API at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#text but canät seem to find where I do wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: both "a" and "aa" work for me. what's your java version?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

One possibility is that your default `Locale` has different symbols for AM/PM. When constructing a date format you should always supply a `Locale` unless you really want to use the system's default `Locale`, e.g.:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yy h:mm:ss a", Locale.US)
```

Comment: The lesson here is that when doing date-time work, **always specify the desired/expected Locale and time zone**. If either is omitted, you are implicitly relying on the JVM's current default. Bonus tip: Google "Joda-Time" and "java.time".

Comment: Would be nice if the exception message was not just "Unparseable date" but also the position in the String where it failed...

Comment: If you timestamp already has AM PM attached to the string without a space then use : "M/d/yy h:mm:ssa";

Answer (score 6):

Modern answer:

```
    String datetime = "9/1/10 11:34:35 AM";
    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(datetime, 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yy h:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH));
```

This produces a `LocalDateTime` of 2010-09-01T11:34:35. Beware of two digit years, though; `DateTimeFormatter` will assume 2000 through 2099. For my birthday this would have been incorrect.

We still need to provide the locale. Since AM/PM markers are hardly used in practice in other locales than English, I considered `Locale.ENGLISH` a fairly safe bet. Please substitute your own.

The other answers were fine answers in 2010 and 2011. Already in 2014 the above was valid and I would have preferred it.

Comment: If your input timestamp doesn't have a space between AM PM and then use "M/d/yy h:mm:ssa"

Answer (score 3):

I am taking an example of date given below and print the formatted date into 24-hour format if suits your requirement.

```
 String inputdate="9/1/10 11:34:35 AM";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss aa",Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            System.out.println(""+new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss",Locale.getDefault()).format(simpleDateFormat.parse(inputdate)));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If you still have any query, Please respond. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

You can build a case-insensitive parser using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`. Since a date-time parsing/formatting type (e.g. `DateTimeFormatter`, `SimpleDateFormat` etc.) is `Locale`-sensitive, you should always use a `Locale` with such a type. I've used `Locale.ENGLISH` because your date-time string has AM/PM marker in English.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                .appendPattern("M/d/uu H:m:s a")
                                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        //Test
        Stream.of(
                "9/1/10 11:34:35 AM",
                "9/1/10 11:34:35 am",
                "09/1/10 11:34:35 AM",
                "9/01/10 11:34:35 Am"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(s, dtf)));;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2010-09-01T11:34:35
2010-09-01T11:34:35
2010-09-01T11:34:35
2010-09-01T11:34:35
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: If you timestamp already has AM PM attached to the string without a space then use : .appendPattern("M/d/uu H:m:sa");

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with FreeMarker for Java and pop on this issue use below code. I had this problem, my locale set AM/PM as DE. Not sure why...
`<#setting locale="en_US">`

Answer (score 0):

Just a note about `Locale`: 
the *symbols* used for AM/PM depend on `Locale`!

This affects parsing strings, eventually causing errors if the used AM/PM field does not match the predefined symbols. (obviously also affects formatting)

`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` accept an optional `Locale` when being created. If none is given. the systems default one is used.

---

Warning: using `DateTimeFormatter` the case of the AM/PM flag is also relevant when parsing, at least for some locales.

As an example, the Indian Locale requires the AM/PM flag being lowercase (`am`, `pm`), while some other locales (`ROOT`, `ITALY`, `US`, `GERMANY`) only accept uppercase AM/PM.

This throws `DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-03-31 10:15:30 AM +05:30' could not be parsed at index 20`

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-03-31 10:15:30 AM +05:30",
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a Z", 
                                                new Locale("en", "IN")))
```

This results in `2021-03-31T10:15:30+05:30`

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-03-31 10:15:30 am +05:30",
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a Z", 
                                                new Locale("en", "IN")))
```

Using `Locale.US`, `Locale.GERMANY` or `Locale.ROOT`, the results are *inverted*.

Note: case of AM/PM does not matter when parsing with `SimpleDateFormat` <sub>(I am not recommending its use, I prefer `DateTimeFormatter`)</sub>