# I have a requirement that is converting a string (2011/05/02 02:55:20 PM) to date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have a requirement that is converting a string (2011/05/02 02:55:20 PM) to date

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to parse DateTime-string with AM/PM marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618676/unable-to-parse-datetime-string-with-am-pm-marker)

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Here is a suggestion for a pattern string and an illustration on how to parse a date:

```
String str = "2011/05/02 02:55:20 PM";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss aa");
Date date = sdf.parse(str);
System.out.println(date);
```

Prints on my system:

```
Mon May 02 14:55:20 CEST 2011
```

Answer (score 0):

use java's OOTB DateFormat: [Read more...](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

The format would then be `yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss aa`