# format date string Thu, 12 Jun 2014 13:15:30 GMT

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

android report this error

```
 W/System.err(31941): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu, 12 Jun 2014 13:15:30 GMT" (at offset 0)
```

this is my dateFormat `"EEE, dd MMM yyyy KK:mm:ss zzz"`

any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference, in minutes, between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216292/difference-in-minutes-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change pattern to

```
EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss z
```

[refer the symbols in detail here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: the same error with this pattern
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss z");

Comment: set `Locale` explicitly then like `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss z", Locale.EN_US)`

Answer (score 1):

`KK` (00-11) format use like 00, 01,..11. whereas  `kk` (01-24) format use like 01, 02..24.
and for `GMT` use `z` instead of `zzz`

So try below format as dateformat

```
EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss z
```

For more info see [Formatting hour using SimpleDateFormat](http://www.java-examples.com/formatting-hour-using-simpledateformat)