# Java 17: DateTimeFormatter not localising AM/PM marker

Tags: java, time, localization, java-17, datetimeformatter

I currently am migrating a piece of software from Java 11 to Java 17 and noticed that `DateTimeFormatter` has changed its behaviour when formatting time that contains the AM/PM marker. Earlier, that marker would have been localised (e.g. `vorm.` for AM in German) and now, it stays AM. This is not a locale-specific issue, because I already have tried this with other locales. The pattern that is being tried here is `HH:mm:ss a`, where `a` is the place holder of the marker. How can the previous behaviour be restored?

The `DateTimeFormatter` is being called using the `ofPattern` method as follows:
`ofPattern("HH:mm:ss a", Locale.GERMANY).format(now)`.
The variable `now` is a LocalDateTime object.

Comment: Are you sure that worked with java 11 without a custom formater? I don't think so. You have probably used a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and appended a custom `ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY` to it. I would be surprised if it worked since it is not usual to format dates having `vorm.` and `nachm.`  as a subtitute for `am/pm`. Besides `HH` is for 24 hour format; it should be `hh:mm ....`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44411475/how-to-change-am-pm-symbol-to-my-own-alphabet-when-using-java-8-date-time-api

Comment: @Eritrean Yes, I'm sure that it worked under Java 11 without any custom formatter because the code has not been changed and it really is as mentioned in the question. No, the code is not using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` but I have now looked into that method `ofPattern` and that is using the builder: `return new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern(pattern).toFormatter(locale);` I agree that localised substitutes are rare but it's a requirement. You're right about the pattern but I didn't define mine.

Comment: Just in case of someone asking: Replacing the pattern `HH:mm:ss a` to `hh:mm:ss a` did not change the output in this case.

Comment: It’s probably the locale data bundled with Java 17 being different, not the formatter class itself.

Comment: I can only partially reproduce your observations in my Java 17.  While for locales `Locale.GERMAN` and `Locale.GERMANY` I do get `PM`, for many other locales I do not. Including locales of language codes he, lv, yi, cs, el, af, sa, fa, lb and no.

Comment: It seems the locale data is the same - for example https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11/blob/master/src/jdk.localedata/share/classes/sun/text/resources/ext/JavaTimeSupplementary_de.java#L84 vs https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/master/src/jdk.localedata/share/classes/sun/text/resources/ext/JavaTimeSupplementary_de.java#L84 is both nachm. for German

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem.
I found this:
https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8297504

Basically it says in older unicode CLDR (v33) which java 11 is based on, German terms for AM/PM is nachm. and vorm.

But in CLDR v44 which java17 is based on they changed it to AM/PM.

This is the quote from the ticket(https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8297504):

> It turned out that the change came from the upstream CLDR. In CLDR v33 which JDK 11 is based on, "pm" string is localized into German "nachm." (look for "·de·" in the right column):
> https://www.unicode.org/cldr/cldr-aux/charts/33/by_type/date_&_time.gregorian.html#72c7f54616968b69

> whereas in CLDR v42 which the latest JDK is based on, "pm" string in German is "PM":
> https://unicode-org.github.io/cldr-staging/charts/latest/by_type/date_&_time.gregorian.html#72c7f54616968b69

So the current right way in German based on recent unicode is AM/PM

Comment: You have found the right bug reported for this problem. 

Comment: Please do not share any content as image. A link and a quote would be MUCH better. Please [edit] your answer and use `>` for the quote.

Answer (score 0):

Creating proper datetime format with correct `Chronology` and `Locale` will give am/pm in desired locale. For Germany and Chinese, I was able to get correct data, but for Hindi and Italy it’s not giving expected output. May be this is how data is showed in their respective region.

```
final String pattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.FULL, FormatStyle.FULL, Chronology.ofLocale(Locale.GERMAN),Locale.GERMAN);
final DateTimeFormatter targetFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern).withLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
final String value = ZonedDateTime.now().format(targetFormat);
```