# AM/PM symbol in certain locale is not as expected

Tags: java, locale, simpledateformat

I've found this post which kinda explains half of my problem. which is why my AM symbol is not what I expected.
[Unable to parse DateTime-string with AM/PM marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618676/unable-to-parse-datetime-string-with-am-pm-marker)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfBefore = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US);
// I tried format with 2 [a] as well , MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa
//SimpleDateFormat sdfAfter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);

System.out.println("Debug: test6 = "+sdfBefore.format(System.currentTimeMillis()));
System.out.println("Debug: test7 = "+sdfBefore.parse("05/26/2014 06:57:07 a.m."));
System.out.println("Debug: test8 = "+sdfBefore.parse("05/26/2014 06:57:08 A.M."));
System.out.println("Debug: test9 = "+sdfBefore.parse("05/26/2014 06:57:09 AM"));
```

And here's my result:

```
Debug: test6 = 05/26/2014 07:30:01 a.m.
Debug: test7 = Mon May 26 06:57:07 GMT 2014
Debug: test8 = Mon May 26 06:57:08 GMT 2014
Error: java.text.ParseException: invalid Date syntax in "05/26/2014 06:57:09 AM"
```

Locale I tried so far:

```
German = vorm.
US/ENGLISH/<default>/Canada = a.m.
chinese = ? <--probably cause my sonsole doesn't support it
```

Every example I found online says the english/US locale should be the correct one for the symbol "AM" and "PM"

does anyone notice anything wrong here?

Comment: When I try this, I get the results "Debug: test6 = 05/26/2014 09:36:56 AM" and Unparseable date "05/26/2014 06:57:07 a.m." (which seems to be the correct thing because "a.m." is not a valid AM/PM marker. Which java version do you use?

Comment: version 1.5 , I am currently looking into DateFormatSymbols.setAmPmStrings(newAmpms); see if it helps..

Comment: Didn't get what exact problem you are looking for? May be explain a bit more?

Comment: @JackyCheng Perhaps you should have a look around in the project configuration if there has been tweaked around with these symbols, as this is **not** the normal configuration.

Comment: @UweAllner thanks, I'll take a look. It seems very odd to me as well.

Comment: @Mr.777 My problem is that every example/tutorial on the internet says the locale US/English will have the "AM" "PM" as the symbol of ...well am and pm, which in my test shows that the locale US is using "a.m." "p.m." as the am/pm symbol instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I found a brute force way to fix it, but I'll still be greatful if anyone knows what's the root cause of it.

```
DateFormatSymbols sym = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.US);
sym.setAmPmStrings(new String[] { "AM", "PM"});
SimpleDateFormat sdfBefore = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", sym);

System.out.println("Debug: test6 = "+sdfBefore.format(System.currentTimeMillis()));
System.out.println("Debug: test9 = "+sdfBefore.parse("05/26/2014 06:57:09 AM"));
```

Result:

```
Debug: test6 = 05/26/2014 07:47:44 AM
Debug: test9 = Mon May 26 06:57:09 GMT 2014
```