# Converting from String to DateTime

Tags: java, date, time

I want to convert a `String` of different forms to the `Date` format. Here is my current code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("hhmma"); 
    Date time = sdf.parse(string);
```

Testing it out, it will parse inputs such as `1030pm` correctly. However, it does not work on inputs like `830pm` or any other single digit hours. Is there any way around this? Or do I have to have a different `DateFormat ("hmma")` for different `String` lengths?

Comment: If I tried hmma, 830pm would work just fine. But 1030pm will give me a parse exception.

Comment: I can only think of kludges, like pre-pending a 0 to the String if length is inadequate. Let's see what answers pop up. 1+

Comment: Allow only Dates with length of 6 chars and adding a '0' to ypur String so that every String has to look like 1122pm, 0122pm, 0102pm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3618809/4088809 maybe ?

Comment: What about the minute-of-hour number, will it be padded with a leading zero or not? For example, is `01:02 AM` going to be `12AM` or `102AM`?

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

You apparently have a time-of-day without any date. The `java.util.Date` class, despite its poorly chosen name, represents both a date *and* a time-of-day.

In Java 8 and later, the built-in [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)) offers a time-of-day class called [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). Just what you need for a time-only value.

If the hour may not have a padded leading zero, but the minute will, then I suggest simply prepending a zero when the length of input string is shorter.

```
String input = "834AM";
String s = null;
switch ( input.length () ) {
    case 6:
        s = input;
        break;
    case 5:
        // Prepend a padded leading zero.
        s = "0" + input;
        break;
    default:
        // FIXME: Handle error condition. Unexpected input.
        break;
}
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "hhmma" );
LocalTime localTime = formatter.parse ( s , LocalTime :: from );

System.out.println ( "Input: " + input + " → s: " + s + " → localTime: " + localTime );
```

When run.

> Input: 834AM → s: 0834AM → localTime: 08:34

If, on the other hand, a minute number below 10 will be a single digit without a padded leading zero, I have no solution. Seems to me that would be impossibly ambiguous. For example, does `123AM` mean `01:23AM` or `12:03AM`?

---

**Tip:** Stick with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats, specifically 24-hour clock and leading zeros.