# SimpleDateFormat: parsing exception on android 6 devices

Tags: android, date, parsing, kotlin

I'm trying to receive a string to a date. Here's an example of the string:

```
val date = "10/10/2016 12:00:00 AM" //format month/day/year
```

Now, I'd like to convert this string into a date. To do that, I'm trying to run the following:

```
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa")
var date = formatter.parse(date)
```

Whenever this code is running on devices running android 8, everything works out great. However, if I try to run in older devices (ex.: phones using Android 6), I end up with a ParseException:

```
Unparseable date: "10/10/2016 12:00:00 AM" (at offset 20)
```

I've noticed that removing the AM/PM characters `(aa)` from the string solves the parsing exception. Can someone please tell me what's going on here?

thanks

Regards,
Luis

PS: the code runs without any problem in the emulator, but not in real devices

Comment: From here  : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat?hl=pt-br

In the examples and patterns, they only use one 'a' char for the PM/AM marker, Could you try that ?

Comment: are you getting time from date picker or time picker ?

Comment: Getting the date from web service... Unfortunately, it was formatted to a string in the format I've shown...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
val date = "10/10/2016 12:00:00 AM"
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US)
var date = formatter.parse(date)
```

Got from here : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat?hl=pt-br

Looks like they never use `"aa"` for `"PM/AM"` value but rather `"a"` or `"aaa"`.

Also from this response : [Unable to parse DateTime-string with AM/PM marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618676/unable-to-parse-datetime-string-with-am-pm-marker) 
They recommend changing your default `Locale` To `Locale.US` if you have different symbols for PM/AM

Comment: Hello. That was my initial string... Since it wasn't working, I've tried using aa...

Comment: Did your using `Locale` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618676/unable-to-parse-datetime-string-with-am-pm-marker ?